# Filter group contains specific values

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I want to filter group with specific values. Take the sample data below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'comp': ['a','b','a','b','c','d', 'c', 'c', 'd'], 'grid': [1,2,2,4,1,2,1,2,2]})
```

The `df`:

```
  comp  grid  val
0    a     1   10
1    b     2   11
2    a     2   12
3    b     4   13
4    c     1   14
5    d     2   15
6    c     1   16
7    c     2   17
8    d     2   18
```

I want to groupby `comp` and check if in each group the `grid` has at least one value 1 and one value 2. The expect outcome is group `a` and group `c`

```
  comp  grid  val
0    a     1   10
2    a     2   12
4    c     1   14
6    c     1   16
7    c     2   17
```

I try with `groupby` and `transform` but not successful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with compare `set`s:

```
#if contains 1,2 and some another values
df = df[df.groupby('comp')['grid'].transform(lambda x: set(x) >= set([1,2]))]
print (df)
  comp  grid
0    a     1
2    a     2
4    c     1
6    c     1
7    c     2

#if contains only 1,2 
df = df[df.groupby('comp')['grid'].transform(lambda x: set(x) == set([1,2]))]
print (df)
  comp  grid
0    a     1
2    a     2
4    c     1
6    c     1
7    c     2
```

If need at least one `1` and one `2` is possible use:

```
intersect = np.intersect1d(df.loc[df['grid'].eq(1),'comp'], df.loc[df['grid'].eq(2),'comp'])
print (intersect)
['a' 'c']

df = df[df['comp'].isin(intersect)]
print (df)
  comp  grid
0    a     1
2    a     2
4    c     1
6    c     1
7    c     2
```